# What do these conda package resolution warnings mean and can they be safely ignored?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I ran the command `conda update anaconda`. Here is the output;

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
Warning: 4 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - anaconda::_py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0, anaconda::libxgboost-0.90-0
  - anaconda::_py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0, defaults::libxgboost-0.90-0
  - anaconda::libxgboost-0.90-0, defaults::_py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0
  - defaults::_py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0, defaults::libxgboost-0.90done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

What do the warnings mean exactly? I am unable to fix the warnings. Can these warnings be ignored safely without side effect?

I am running python 3.7 on anaconda.

Comment: Could you please include your `conda info` in the question, or at least the channels you have configured (e.g., `conda config --get channels`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
conda update conda
```

If it doesn't works try, sometimes due to the version issue you get the error

```
conda install conda=4.6
```

Yes you can ignore the warnings, if you can use the library, then it won't create an issue

Comment: Can the warnings be ignored since they are not errors? Any side effect if the warnings remain?

Comment: Yes, if you can use the library, then it won't create an issue. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it.